# Solution to download multiple files for thousands of users

Tags: windows-server-2008, load-balancing

We have a business need and should allow 2000 PCs to download 150 - 200 Mb (10 - 20 files) as fast as possible. The download will start when something from server will trigger it. All PCs are pooling the server to find if they are allow to download the package. New packages will be available in 10-15 days.

The question is: what architecture do we need ? How many servers do we need ? It is HTTP downloading a viable solution or we should think at TCP/IP solution over Sockets ? For HTTP do you recommend Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7 or something else ?

The transfer is over the web, the PCs are distributed in all the country.

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see how the SQL db is relevant to this question. Can you specify why it is? Also, if you're on a LAN, FTP is generally faster

Comment: It's not, I changed the question and specified that the transfer is over the web.

Comment: Ok, I'm about to incur bad karmic points up the wazoo for suggesting this, but have you considered doing a closed net P2P setup?   There are some large application distributions that use it with a pretty high degree of success.  Simply making the file available should be easy enough to trigger a download once available. Plus you get the added benefit of all the clients sharing without having to distribute 2000 copies yourself.  Iain suggestion of using a CDN is likely a more proven and reliable method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The enterprise solutions one would typically expect to see are:

- caching proxy servers (possibly pre-seeded outside of business hours after the content was updated)
- alternatively WAN accellerators

assuming of course that all users/PC's are to download the same files and they are somewhat grouped in branch offices.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this if you are using public infrastructure is to sign up for a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) service, it's what they're good at.